# REST API - Generate token by passing private key with timestamp using HMAC-SHA512 in python

Tags: python, rest, hash, hmac, sha512

I need to get a API Token first to pull the Data. In order to get token i need to make a API call using a private key

Any reference please?

Comment: No expert on this, but a 404 error would indicate you have the wrong URL.  Double check it maybe?

Comment: URL is perfectly fine, I guess the problem is with either passing HMAC Sign or timestamp